# Blackberry Backward Support: The specific cases of "net.rim.device.api.ui.decor" package and "TouchEvent" class

Tags: blackberry, java-me

**The situation:**

I'm developing an application for Blackberry 8310. With this device, the greatest allowed OS version is v4.5.0 !!! So, I managed to use the latest compatible SDK, mainly the JDK 4.5 in combination with eclipse plugin.
In my project, I used the advanced UI code provided by RIM, for backward compatibility and for the great user experience it offers.
In the [readme file](https://github.com/blackberry/Samples-for-Java/tree/master/Advanced%20UI) of the advanced UI, it says that all sources are compatible with JDK 4.2.

**The problem:**
The problem is that I developed all my User Interface code with the Advanced UI but this requires a package and a class from JDK version greater than 4.5, which is greater than what I can run.

**My Question**
The actual question is: How could I manage to use some classes(or package if possible) from JDK version greater than than JDK4.5 while developing with JDK4.5?
I unsuccesfully tried some tricks; one of them is: 
"class dump" : go inside the JDK5.0, take the missing files (.class files), add them to the project and edit the .classpath of eclipse.

Comment: There's no need to use the `TouchEvent` class on a device running OS 4.5.  There are no 4.5 devices with touchscreens (the oldest is 4.7).  If you just want to use one set of source code, that contains some code that's only available on later OS versions, use preprocessor directives for that.

Comment: Thanks Nate for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

Reference your question `How could I manage to use some classes(or package if possible) from JDK version greater than than JDK4.5 while developing with JDK4.5?`, please note that the BlackBerry Apps are forward compatible ONLY. This means you cannot develop your App on JDK version greater than 4.5 and expect it run on devices running OS 4.5.

Comment: Sarah, I know that BlackBerry Apps are ONLY backward compatible but in my actual situation, What I need is to make JDK 4.5 evolve a bit like the "Advanced UI" did. I just want a support for "net.rim.device.api.ui.decor" with, of course, implied dependencies satistied.

Comment: @user2565393 not backward compatible but forward compatible. If you want to imitate the `net.rim.device.api.ui.decor` class you can try with extensive coding. If you mention what exact are you trying to create from the `Advanced UI`, we can probably answer your query better.

Comment: you are right, ONLY Forward. What I'm trying to do is : use FielSet class from Advanced UI source code.

Comment: You can create custom fields to imitate the behavior of the `Advanced UI`. Check this link if it helps: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Create_a_custom_field_508117_11.jsp